# How to make a ramp function that starts in point a and finishes in point b. [a,b]. And with value 0 outside the interval

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

I want to build a ramp function that starts from point a and finishes in point b. [a,b].

I have constructed a code of a ramp function that starts from 0 and finishes in point b.[0,b].

this is the code:

```
hold on
b =2  % time in which the ramp finish
a=1  %time in which the ramp start
t = [0:0.01:15]';  %timespan of the ramp function
for impAmp = [3 5 10]  %height of the ramp 
function
rampOn = @(t) t<=b;
ramp =@(t) t.*impAmp.*rampOn(t);
plot(t,ramp(t))
end
```

But I want to define a new code of the ramp function defined in the interval [a,b]. And a value of 0 outside the interval.

I have tried this code. But it modified all the ramp function.

```
hold on
b =2 % time in which the ramp finish
a=1 %time in which the ramp start
t = [0:0.01:15]';%timespan of the ramp function
for impAmp = [3 5 10]%height of the ramp function
rampOn = @(t) a<t<=b;
ramp =@(t) t.*impAmp.*rampOn(t);
plot(t,ramp(t))
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a function, you have:

```
function y=ramp(x,a,b,h)
    y = h/(b-a)*(x-a).*(x>a).*(x<b);
end
```

As a function handle,

```
f = @(x,a,b,h) h/(b-a)*(x-a).*(x>a).*(x<b);
```

Either way, define the parameters `a`, `b` and the height `h` and use the function as you want:

```
a = 1; 
b = 4;
h = 7;
x = 0:0.1:5;
y = ramp(x,a,b,h);
plot(x,y)

a = 2; 
b = 2.5;
h = 10;
x = 0:0.1:5;
plot(x,ramp(x,a,b,h))
```